# Не выполняется отправка формы

Tags: php, html

День добрый! Столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо отправить форму по клику на кнопку на электронный ящик, однако при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" браузер просто переходит на страницу скрипта и выдает Not Found. Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста.
Сама форма:

```
<form id="application" action=" application.php" method="POST" name=" application ">
      <input name="name" id="zayavkaName" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required /><br>
      <input name="email" type="email" id="applicationEmail" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваш E-mail" required /><br>
      <input name="telephone" type="Tel" id="applicationTelephone" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required/><br>
      <button class="applicationButton btn btn-default btn-lg btn-contact" type="submit" form="application">Записаться</button>
    </form>
```

Сам aplication.php

```
<?php 


$sendto   = "myemail@email.com"; 
$username = $_POST['name'];
$usertel = $_POST['telephone'];
$usermail = $_POST['email']; 

$subject  = "Новое сообщение";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Cообщение с сайта</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>От кого:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Сайт:</strong> ".$usertel."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";


if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
  echo "<center><p>Спасибо!</p></center>";
} else {
    echo "<center><p>Что-то пошло не так!</p></center>";
}

?>
```

Comment: уберите пробел перед названием файла тут `action=" application.php"`

Comment: Отправляйте не через <button type='submit'> а через <input type="submit" name="enter" />. И сделайте проверку по типу if ( isset($_POST['enter'])) { если нажали на энтер, то выполнить этот код }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, на сервере был отключен php. Вопрос решен.